# Mathematica can't integrate my function

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I was trying to calculate the definite integral

$$
\int_0^.0076\int_0^.0425\int_0^.1275\frac{1}{x^2+y^2+z^2}\,dz\,dy\,dx
$$

I entered this:

```
Integrate[1/(x^2 + y^2 + z^2) {z, 0, .1275}, {y, 0, .0425}, {x, 0, .0076}]
```

But Mathematica returned the following:

$$
\int_0^{0.1275}\int_0^{0.0425}\frac{\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{0.0076}{\sqrt{y^2+z^2}}\right)}{\sqrt{y^2+z^2}}\,dy\,dz
$$

I even tried finding a definite integral in order to make sure that there was no problem with the bounds of integration and still no luck. Any ideas on what I can do to solve the integral or at least estimate the solution?

Comment: You need a comma between your integrand and the variables.  Also, just try NIntegrate.  The answer is:  $0.0382918$.

Answer (score 2):

As @David G. Stork pointed out, a comma is absent. Besides, it seems that you are not interested in a precise result, so you can use `NIntegrate`, which is more suitable for numerical integral evaluation than `Integrate`. The `Method` is added to avoid some warnings, e.g., slowly converging.

```
NIntegrate[1/(x^2 + y^2 + z^2), {z, 0, .1275}, {y, 0, .0425}, {x, 0, .0076}, Method -> "LocalAdaptive"]
```

> 0.0382918

Comment: Well, the `ArcTan` showing up means that Mathematica performed at least the integration over `x`, so OP must have made an error while copying the originally syntactically correct code from Mathematica. Still, (+1) for showing `NIntegrate` with `Method -> "LocalAdaptive"`.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher Yes, I think so. Also `Integrate[......]//N` can obtain the desired result but with a slower speed.

Comment: If you want to get results faster (especially with higher precision goals) you can use `Method -> {"GlobalAdaptive", 
  "SingularityHandler" -> "DuffyCoordinates"}` .